# How can I shorten my code using Factories with Angular and Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

So I started using `AngularFire` and in all of my code in my controllers, I have these:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("contacts").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(Auth.$getAuth().uid);
$scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(ref);

  $scope.contacts.$add({
    uid: Auth.$getAuth().uid,
    contactNumber: contactNumber,
    displayName: displayName,
    created_at: timestamp
  }).then(function (ref) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Success',
      template: 'Contact added to your travel safe.'
    });
  });

$scope.removeContact = function (d) {
  var contactsDeleteRef = firebase.database().ref().child("contacts");
  var contact = $firebaseArray(contactsDeleteRef);
  contact.$loaded()
    .then(function (value) {
      contact.$remove(contact.$getRecord(d)).then(function (ref) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Success',
          template: 'Contact removed from your travel safe.'
        });
      }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
}
```

As you can see, I keep on repeating those in my controllers and I'm looking on some way to make it shorter because I want to make it testable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you move this code into service?